# How to convert a text file into a numpy array or a list of lists in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, loops, numpy-ndarray

I have a text file as follows:
[image]

Now, I would like to load it into a numpy array or a list of lists which should be in the same order as that of the image above. So, I have to get an array with 3 columns and the number of rows present in the file.

I have used the following code below:

```
import os
a = open(os.getcwd()+'a.txt', 'r')
a = a.read()
```

But, I am getting an output as follows which is not a list or an array and is not what I wanted: 
[image]

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Your code is attempting to read() a directory. It should raise IsADirectoryError

Comment: Just check it now. I have added the file name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert a space-delimited file into a list of lists.

```
with open('a.txt') as g:
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in g.readlines()]
```